# Have function to show subsets of a string - now trying to adapt code to handle arrays

Tags: javascript, recursion, subset

Some working code is on the bottom. But my poorly adapted code on the top goes into an infinite recursion loop.
What is it I do not know about arrays?

```
function recSubsets(soFar, rest)
{
    if (rest===[]) console.log(soFar);

    else
    {
        recSubsets(soFar.push(rest[0])), rest.slice(1));
        recSubsets(soFar, rest.slice(1));
    }
}  


function listSubsets(s)
{
    recSubsets([],s);
}

listSubsets([4,9,3,77])
```

below is the working version for strings

```
function recSubsets(soFar, rest)
{
    if (rest==="") console.log(soFar);

    else
    {
        recSubsets(soFar+rest[0], rest.substring(1));
        recSubsets(soFar, rest.substring(1));
    }
}  


function listSubsets(s)
{
    recSubsets("",s);
}

listSubsets("cat")
```

gives me:

cat
ca
ct
c
at
a
t

Comment: Could you show us the output you're expecting for your example input?

Comment: I added it to the bottom... It seems that my function is not treating an array like an array. And I don't see why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two problems -

1. push does not return an array(returns the new length of the array)
2. your stopping condition did not work. checking length === 0 instead works.

   ```
   function recSubsets(soFar, rest)
   {
       if (rest.length===0) console.log(soFar);

       else
       {
           var newSoFar = soFar.slice();
           newSoFar.push(rest[0]);
           recSubsets(newSoFar, rest.slice(1));
           recSubsets(soFar, rest.slice(1));
       }
   }  


   function listSubsets(s)
   {
       recSubsets([],s);
   }

   listSubsets([4,9,3,77])
   ```

Comment: I was just fiddling around with creating a version of "newSoFar", but I would have never thought that if (rest===[]) was wrong. Thanks!